# How to review WordPress website php version compatibility?

Tags: plugins, php, upgrade

My host is upgrading php version from 5.4 to 5.6. 
I cannot see https:// pages nor login wp-admin with the test sites to see issues.
I've read somewhere that WordPress recommends php 5.6. BUT, I don't know if the plugins have any issues.
However, I am able to see that there are no errors in the error log.
Does no php parsing error mean everything is compatible?

Answer (score 2):

By default WP is very reluctant to show or display any errors. That's inline with its strategy of "dumbing down" things of sorts.

The configuration I use to monitor for errors is along the lines of this in `wp-config.php`:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
@ini_set( 'display_errors','Off' );

@ini_set( 'log_errors','On' );
@ini_set( 'error_log','/home/user/logs/php_site_name.log' );
```

There is also WP native `WP_DEBUG_LOG` constant, but unfortunately they chose to make it hardcoded to write log into public content directory, which is bad practice.

And yes, overall updating to newer version PHP usually results in breakage and errors if something is incompatible. Not much else to do, short of code review of everything.

Comment: if I don't see any error log, does it mean everything works fine? What if I see errors, how can I fix it? Ask plugin developer to update?

Comment: Probably. It depends. Yes.